# CSS drop caps wrongly positioned in IE9 with em padding

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, margin, font-size

This is more of an intriguing problem than anything else since I have managed to solve it, but not with a solution that I find entirely satisfying. I'd rather know why the problem occurs to better understand it.

I have several paragraphs with drop-caps on the first letters using CSS3 pseudo-selectors. This displays fine in FF, Opera and Safari but not IE9. The problem is the em units I'm using as padding to position the letter. If I change these to px the letter displays fine in all browsers; BUT I'm not happy mixing px and em on my text. I assume this has something to do with how IE9 renders em units.

```css
p {
    margin:0 0 1.5em 0;
    text-align:justify;
    font:1em/1.5 Georgia, Palatino, "Palatino Linotype", "Palatino LT STD", "Book Antiqua", serif;
}
.post-content p:first-child:first-letter {
    float:left;
    color:#444;
    font-size:3.3em;
    padding:0.1em 0.1em 0 0;
    line-height:0.7em;
    text-shadow:2px 2px 0 #dadada;
}
```

```html
<section class="post-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet mi ut erat dapibus varius. Cras aliquet augue eget ipsum posuere a mattis quam gravida. Proin pretium rhoncus mi, nec dapibus odio iaculis id. Aenean mattis, nulla eu hendrerit fermentum, urna tellus tristique mauris, eu dignissim quam arcu ut nisi.</p>
</section>
```

I've made a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/C5zsv/

Comment: Interesting question. Somehow the :first-letter bit gets a seperate treatment from a good-old span: [see this fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thHBr/), which works in IE9.

Comment: Yes, I did try using a span, it's bizarre that that works differently. I'm not content with that as a solution though. I might be wrong but I have a sneaking suspicion that ie9 is maybe taking the padding size as relative to the :first-letter font-size whereas the rest are using a padding size relative to the main paragraph text.  Unfortuntely I don't know any way to confirm that suspicion as Firebug doesn't show you the calculated padding size (in px) of a pseudo-selector.

Comment: Aye, it's not a good solution. Your suspicion seems reasonable. I may be tempted to try out the fiddle later this week at very large sizes and just measure the pixels, to see if it's consistent with your theory.

Comment: Funny thing is: [MSDN on first-letter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530753(VS.85).aspx) suggests to use this selector for drop-caps.

Comment: Well I suppose it does work fine for drop-caps in ie9, the problem is the padding needed to position the letter is calculated differently from other browsers.

Comment: @Jeroen I've found a blog post from back in 2009 with comment on this issue. http://nickcowie.com/2009/drop-caps-first-letter-and-firefox/ Although he advocates using a seperate ie stylesheet, which seems extreme simply for drop-caps! I might end up having to give up and resort to px if (as is looking to be the case) there is no solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, this question felt like a wonderful black box puzzle to me, so I tried to gather some evidence to support any answers. Turns out various browsers render the combination of `em` and `:first-letter` quite differently.

First up, here's the code I used to test this (a fork of the question's fiddle):

```
<p>Yyy is a<br />tall letter<br />indeed.</p>
<p>&Ntilde;ino has a<br />tall letter<br />as well.</p>
<p>ggg has a<br />big bottom<br />ahw yeah.</p>
```

And the CSS:

```
p {
    margin: 0 0 1.0em 0;
    font: 3em/1.5 Georgia;
    background-color: #CCE;
}
p:first-letter {
    float: left;
    font-size: 3.3em;
    padding: 0.1em 0.1em 0 0;
    line-height: 0.7em;
    background-color: #DFD;
}
```

Check out [the new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JaxLr/)

How this renders in various browsers:

[image: First-letter in various browsers]

Basically ***the answer to this SO question*** (or at least bottom line, no pun intended) seems to be: mixing `em` and `first-letter` leaves your site at the mercy of the browser and the font-family. And boy, are the not merciful.

This "mercy" has a few interesting features as well:

- Chrome (125px) and IE (134px) keep a consistent height for the first-letter, but FF decides to give Ñ some extra height.
- FF almost always keeps the letter inside the actual box (with the exception of the top-left part of the Y, but all 3 browsers do this).
- Chrome and IE both allow the Ñ and lowercase g to go outside the box.
- Not one of the three browsers has the *bottom of the second line of text* aligned with the actual *bottom part of the first-letter*.
- Setting the padding in px does improve the capital Y situation in IE, however for me this kept screwing things up in FF and Chrome.
- As expected results vary wildly when you change the font-family.
- Last but not least: it's just the first-letter that's not behaving consistently. The three regular lines of text are quite similar (perhaps even identical?) in these three browsers.

### Info from w3.org

In the CSS3-linebox module there is some info on [baseline alignment](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-linebox/#baseline) that seems relevant to these issues. May have to read on a bit to see what the status is on that (or perhaps someone here can add it?).

Comment: This confirms all my experimentation, but is in much more detail, so I've marked as the answer as it seems there is no real solution (for now!).

Comment: I think that the quick solution to fix this is using PX instead of EM. I've done this already on a customer website and works very well on IE9-11, FF and Chrome.